# .NET 6 System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer Deserialize UTF-8 escaped string

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, system.text.json

I have some JSON files (facebook backup) which is UTF-8 encoded but special charachters are escaped. The escaped characters are also UTF-8 encoded but in hexadecimal format. For example:

```json
{
  "sender_name": "Tam\u00c3\u00a1s"
}
```

I want to use System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer for deserialization. The problem it is interprets the escaped hexes as UTF-16 characters.
So it will be deserealized as "TamÃ¡s" not as "Tamás" as it should.

Code to repro:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

class Msg
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sender_name")]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
}   

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = @"{
            ""sender_name"": ""Tam\u00c3\u00a1s""
        }";
        var msg = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Msg>(data);
        Console.WriteLine(msg.SenderName);
    }
}
```

Can i change the serializer to interpret it as UTF-8?

Comment: The meaning of the `\uXXXX` escape sequences is specified by the [JSON Proposal](https://json.org) as well as the [JSON Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7). It is defined such that XXXX is the characters "4HEXDIG" Unicode codepoint value.  (characters not in the Basic Multilingual Plane use two sequential escape sequences, e.g. `\uD834\uDD1E`).  I don't think there is any way to make System.Text.Json interpret the `XXXX` values as being anything other than Unicode codepoint values.  You may need to use a Regex to fix your JSON before deserializing.

Comment: Also, you wrote, *The escaped characters are also UTF-8 encoded but in hexadecimal format.* -- but [`U+00C3`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3/index.htm) is in fact **Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE'**.  Thus `Ã` is the correct interpretation of `\u00c3` according to the JSON standard, and your JSON escape sequences were encoded wrongly.  You should get whoever generated the JSON to fix their code.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The json is from Facebook's backup your data feature. So, i have to fix it. Is there any helper method which can help to fix it or i have to write my own regex code?

Comment: I don't know of a a serializer that has a built-in method for fixing the numerical values of JSON escape sequences.  `Utf8JsonReader` has [`ValueSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuespan), [`ValueSequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuesequence) and [`ValueIsEscaped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valueisescaped) so maybe you could do some manual mapping in a `JsonConverter<string>.Read()` method.

Comment: But actually, do you know how `\u00c3\u00a1` is supposed to get mapped to `á` [U+00E1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E1)?  Without knowing the logic behind the erroneous encoding, it's hard to know how to fix it.

Comment: I might miss the point of your question but the only thing i know is that they used UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 for escaping. The `á` UTF-8 representations is `\u00c3\u00a1` or `0xC3 0xA1`.

If your question is about the exact solution. I don't know the conversion algorithm from UTF-8 encoding to UTF-16.
I found a [python solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6bg57h/comment/dhmdikg/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to it but i don't know how to translate it into .NET

Comment: Maybe the following PowerShell (`.NET` based) code snippet could help: ```[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'utf-8').GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetBytes(  $msg.sender_name))```? For tested string `Tam\u00c3\u00a1s \u00C4\u008D` returns (correct) `Tamás č`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the sender of your JSON has wrong values `\u00c3` and `\u00a1` for the numeric escape codes for `á` inside their string literal.  The meaning of the `\uXXXX` escape sequences is specified by the [JSON Proposal](https://json.org) as well as the [JSON Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7). It is defined such that XXXX is the character's "4HEXDIG" UTF-16 Unicode codepoint value <sup>[1]</sup>, which, for `á`, is `\u00E1`.  Instead the provider of your JSON file (Facebook's "backup your data feature" apparently) is using **UTF-8 Hex values** for the `\uXXXX` escape sequences, rather than UTF-16 as required by the standard.

There is no built-in way to tell System.Text.Json (or Json.NET for that matter) that the `\uXXXX` escape sequences use nonstandard values, however [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader) provides access to the underlying, raw byte stream via the [`ValueSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuespan) and [`ValueSequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuesequence) properties, so it is possible to create a custom [`JsonConverter<string>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1) that does the necessary decoding and unescaping itself.

First, create the following converter:

```
public class StringConverterForUtf8EscapedCharValues : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.String)
            throw new JsonException();

        if (!reader.ValueIsEscaped)
            return reader.GetString();

        ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = reader.HasValueSequence ? reader.ValueSequence.ToArray() : reader.ValueSpan;

        // Normally a JSON string will be a utf8 byte sequence with embedded utf18 escape codes.  
        // These improperly encoded JSON strings are utf8 byte sequences with embedded utf8 escape codes.

        var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var maxCharCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxCharCount(4);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
        {
            if (span[i] != '\\')
            {
                Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[maxCharCount];
                var n = decoder.GetChars(span.Slice(i, 1), chars, false);
                sb.Append(chars.Slice(0, n));
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == '"')
            {
                sb.Append('"');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == '\\')
            {
                sb.Append('\\');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == '/')
            {
                sb.Append('/');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'b')
            {
                sb.Append('\u0008');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'b')
            {
                sb.Append('\u0008');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'f')
            {
                sb.Append('\u0008');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'f')
            {
                sb.Append('\u000C');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'f')
            {
                sb.Append('\u000C');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'n')
            {
                sb.Append('\n');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 'r')
            {
                sb.Append('\r');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 1 && span[i+1] == 't')
            {
                sb.Append('\t');
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < span.Length - 5 && span[i+1] == 'u')
            {
                Span<char> hexchars = stackalloc char[4] { (char)span[i+2], (char)span[i+3], (char)span[i+4], (char)span[i+5] };
                if (!byte.TryParse(hexchars, NumberStyles.HexNumber, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out var b))
                {
                    throw new JsonException();
                }
                Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[maxCharCount];
                Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[1] { b };
                var n = decoder.GetChars(bytes, chars, false);
                sb.Append(chars.Slice(0, n));
                i += 5;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }
        }
        var s = sb.ToString();
        return s;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(value);
}
```

And now you will be able to do

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new StringConverterForUtf8EscapedCharValues() },
};
var msg = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Msg>(data, options);
Assert.That(msg?.SenderName?.StartsWith("Tamás") == true); // Succeeds
Console.WriteLine(msg?.SenderName); // Prints Tamás
```

Notes:

- Since a JSON file is generally a UTF-8 encoded character stream, decoding a single string literal in a well-formed JSON file can require decoding a mixture of UTF-8 and UTF-16 values.
- The converter may not work if the underlying byte stream was not encoded using UTF-8.
- Writing with (incorrect) UTF-8 values for escaped characters is not implemented.
- The incorrect escaped values should be fixed before the JSON string literal is decoded to a c# `string` because the presence or absence of escape sequences is lost once decoding and unescaping are complete.
- I haven't tested performance.  It might be more performant to use the decoder returned by `Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder()` to decode in chunks, rather than byte-by-byte as is done in this prototype.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBqgxy).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Characters not in the Basic Multilingual Plane should use two sequential escape sequences, e.g. `\uD834\uDD1E`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answear. It works just fine for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
    var msg = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Msg>(data);

    msg.SenderName= DecodeFromUtf16ToUtf8(msg.SenderName); // Tamás

public  string DecodeFromUtf16ToUtf8(string utf16String)
{
    // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
    byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[utf16String.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < utf16String.Length; ++i)
            utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)utf16String[i];
    
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
}
```

or you can add the json constructor

```
var msg = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Msg>(data);

public class Msg
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sender_name")]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    
    public Msg(string SenderName)
    {
        this.SenderName= DecodeFromUtf16ToUtf8(SenderName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also a working solution.