# Decode Json with unknown charset

Tags: c#, json, decode, jsondecoder

I have current JSON like this:

```json
{
  "group_admin_actions": {
    "group_admin_actions": [
      {
        "actions": [
          {
            "timestamp": 1653403902,
            "action": 3,
            "target_user_name": "\u00d0\u00a4\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d0\u00a4\u00d1\u008d\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b8"
          }
        ],
        "group_name": "\u00d0\u00a6\u00d1\u0096\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0096 \u00d0\u00a4\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The group_name & target_user_name fields in the original version has a Cyrillic entry, but when exporting, it turns out like this.

How to decode it into Cyrillic JSON with C#?

Comment: Exporting from where? What "original version"?

Comment: @AKX from facebook

Comment: From the [JSON RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt): "JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this technically, it's just a little verbose. Any good JSON parser will read this correctly. What are you using to export it?

Comment: @KlausGütter: That doesn't really tell you the encoding though. (It's an unfortunate bit of wording IMO.) The subsequent bits are more useful: "The default encoding is UTF-8. Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets."

Comment: @JonSkeet My comment was mainly about the term "Cyrillic JSON" which sounds as if an encoding e.g. in CP 1251 was expected.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Right. There are definitely two aspects to consider: the encoding of the "raw bytes that make up the document" and then the meaning of the `\uxxxx` escape sequences.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in PowerShell variant of `.NET`*): ```$x='"\u00d0\u00a6\u00d1\u0096\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0096 \u00d0\u00a4\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8"';
[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetString(
[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1').GetBytes(
     ($x|ConvertFrom-Json|ConvertTo-Json) ))
``` returns ```"Цікаві Факти"```.

Comment: @JosefZ I would like to implement a solution something like `myJson.Deserialize<MyJsonObj>()`  on .Net without using PowerShell

Comment: do you mean [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0)? Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (at least) what do you have so far and where you are stuck… In C#, there is `Encoding.GetEncoding` instead of  posh's `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding`

Comment: Your problem isn't that the JSON is encoded with an unknown charset. Your problem is that the numeric values used for [string character escaping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7) violate the JSON standard, which states: *If the character is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed  by the lowercase letter u, **followed by four hexadecimal digits that  encode the character's code point**.* See https://dotnetfiddle.net/OiAVyc which shows that the unescaped characters are nonsense.

Comment: I am not aware of any JSON parser that lets you use nonstandard numeric values for character escaping code point values.  After all the whole idea of character escaping is to avoid encoding issues.

Comment: That being said, the same problem arose recently in the context of [tag:system.text.json]: [.NET 6 System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer Deserialize UTF-8 escaped string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74723845/3744182).  And it turns out the answers there work for you also.  If you create a data model for your JSON then the converter `StringConverterForUtf8EscapedCharValues` from the accepted answer will successfully repair your JSON, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBqgxy.  Does that answer your question?  Your question doesn't specify the JSON serializer that you are using.

Comment: @Charlieface - *Any good JSON parser will read this correctly.* -- actually that's not true.  The numeric values used for the escaped JSON characters aren't Unicode code point values.  They are the values of each byte of the string when encoded as UTF-8, which is a violation of the standard.

Comment: @dbc Yes good point. Although it is still technically valid JSON, it's just not what OP was expecting because it was incorrectly encoded.

Comment: @РоманТимохов - Also, please [edit] your question to specify the serializer you want to use (or clearly indicate that any .NET JSON serializer is sufficient.)  The tag you used, [tag:jsondecoder], *should be used for `JSONDecoder` (introduced in Swift 4) questions for decoding JSON decoder on Apple platforms.*  If you are also using [tag:c#] then you are probably not using this serializer.  Can you confirm please?